# Error "The login failed" en JDBC Java. Funciona perfectamente en una base de datos y falla en la otra

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc, test-ng

Tengo un **proyecto de Java** que usa **JDBC** para realizar la conexión a dos bases de datos de la empresa en la que trabajo. El administrador me dio permisos de acceso con **Autenticación de Windows**. Puedo entrar e interactuar con ambas bases de datos desde **SQL Server Managment Studio**. El problema es que puedo trabajar solo con la primera base de datos desde Java porque al intentar conectarme con la segunda aparece el error **"cannot open database"**.

Es raro porque puedo trabajar con JDBC en la primera base de datos y el servidor principal de ambas bases de datos es el mismo. Adicionalmente, tengo las librerías JDBC y el archivo **sqljdbc_auth.dll**  que se requiere para la Autenticación de Windows. Usé métodos modularizados para evitar errores de tipado. (Cambié algunos caracteres por XXX por razones de seguridad)

```
package Auto;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Test7 
{

    private final static int PORT = 1441;

    /**
     * This is the method that executes the connections
     * @throws Exception 
     */
    @Test
    public void test()
    {
        try
        {
            // === Correct connection with server 1 === //
            String server1Name = "XXXXVPRUBDSQL01\\XXXXDCESQL";
            String databaseName1 = "FacturaElectronicav2";

            String urlServer1 = getURLforconnection(server1Name, databaseName1);
            Connection conn1 = startSQLconnection(urlServer1);

            String table = "dbo.UsersExternal";
            String searcher = "Email";
            String searcherValue = "User@gmail.com";
            String column = "TokenCode";

            String dato = obtainValueFromStatement(conn1, table, searcher, searcherValue, column);

            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("URL connection: " + urlServer1);
            System.out.println("The conenction was created succesful because this was printed");
            System.out.println("Value: " + dato + " // The value obtained from the statement is correct");
            System.out.println("");

            closeSQLConnection(conn1);

            System.out.println("Here goes the connection failure in the second database");
            System.out.println("");

            // === SECOND DATABASE=== //
            String server2Name = "XXXXVPRUBDSQL01\\XXXXDSSINTSQL";
            String databaseName2 = "SISECPrueba";

            String urlServer2 = getURLforconnection(server2Name, databaseName2);

            // Here the connection fails
            Connection conn2 = startSQLconnection(urlServer2);
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            // Here the catch handles the exception while trying to connect to the second database
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    /**
     * Method that creates the url for the connection to the database
     * It uses Windows Authentication [integratedSecurity=true]
     * @param serverName Name of the server connection
     * @param databaseName Name of the database of the server
     * @return The url for the JDBC connection
     */
    public String getURLforconnection(String serverName, String databaseName)
    {
        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://"+serverName+":"+PORT+";databaseName="+databaseName+";integratedSecurity=true";
        return url;
    }

    /**
     * Creates the connection with the database
     * @param URL URL for the JDBC connection
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public Connection startSQLconnection(String URL) throws Exception
    {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL);
        return conn;
    }

    /**
     * Closes the connection with the database
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public void closeSQLConnection(Connection Con) throws Exception
    {
        Con.close();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the value searched in the database by the parameters
     * @param Table Table where the value is
     * @param Searcher Identifier of the search
     * @param SearcherValue Value of the identifier
     * @param Column Column of the table
     * @return The value of the statement
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public String obtainValueFromStatement(Connection Con, String Table, String Searcher, String SearcherValue, String Column) throws Exception
    {
        String answer = "";

        String SQLstatement = "SELECT * FROM " + Table + " WHERE " + Searcher + " = '" + SearcherValue + "'";
        Statement statement = Con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(SQLstatement);

        if(rs.next()) { answer = rs.getString(Column); }
        else { throw new Exception("It can not be found a registry in the statement"); }

        statement.close();
        rs.close();

        return answer;
    }

}
```

El resultado esperado es una conexión correcta a ambas bases de datos. Sin embargo, solo la primera conexión es exitosa ya que el valor obtenido de la tabla de la base de datos es impreso en consola mientras que la conexión con la segunda base de datos falla como se observa en la salida de consola:

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running TestSuite

URL connection: jdbc:sqlserver://XXXXVPRUBDSQL01\XXXXDCESQL:1441;databaseName=FacturaElectronicav2;integratedSecurity=true
The conenction was created succesful because this was printed
Value: 1CE9AAB6-DEC4-481F-81E9-45DAB1D018CC // The value obtained from the statement is correct

Here goes the connection failure in the second database

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot open database "SISECPrueba" requested by the login. The login failed. ClientConnectionId:d122e604-a8e2-4fa7-b1dc-aec3f6e6d9fd
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:213)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:246)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:83)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:2908)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:2242)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:41)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:2228)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5574)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1734)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1355)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1022)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:858)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
        at Auto.Test7.startSQLconnection(Test7.java:86)
        at Auto.Test7.test(Test7.java:56)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:283)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:75)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:373)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:334)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:119)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:407)
```

El problema parece deberse a la conexión específica a la base de datos  **SISECPrueba** del segundo servidor porque la instancia del éste es correcta.

Finalmente, como mencioné anteriormente, tengo acceso normal a ambos servidores desde la aplicación de escritorio **SQL Server Managment Studio** mediante  Autenticación de Windows .

Comment: La conexión la realizas de forma correcta. El problema está en la autenticación. Revisa que el usuario tenga permisos para conectarse a la instancia y a la base de datos. En el log de errores de la instancia puedes ver cual usuario se está utilizando.

Comment: @LuisCazares, Vale muchas gracias, lo revisaré y ya comentaré que encuentro.